# How to change HTML code of the specific page in WordPress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, seo

I need to change HTML code of the specific page in my WordPress website. I just need to add a few lines to the head section.

I tried plugin "What the file" but it contains only the page.php file, that doesn't allow me to change HTML code. Other solutions found in the internet doesn't work as well.

For example, I have following part of the code:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6MR3.png)

I want to add part of the code in the blue brackets, below the title of the specific page.

How is it possible to edit HTML code of the specific website in the editor?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the URL of the page,
then with an if loop loads the custom HTML on the custom page like this:

```
$link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$custom_page = "https://example.com/custom_page/"
if($link == $custom_page){
/// my html
}
```